# Assign multiple rows & columns from one Pandas dataframe to another

Tags: pandas

What's the canonical way to do it? The most obvious syntaxes to me don't work. It's as if Pandas were trying to the whole dataframe to each of the relevant elements.

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,2), dtype=int), columns=['a','b'])
foo2 = foo.copy()
bar = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], index=[1,3], columns=['c','d'])

foo.loc[bar.index,['a','b']] = bar.loc[:,['c','d']] 
# same result for foo.loc[bar.index, :] = bar   
print(foo)
```

Produces:

```
     a    b
0  0.0  0.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  0.0  0.0
3  NaN  NaN
4  0.0  0.0
```

You can, however, make the assignment one series at a time, which requires a loop.

```
for (foo_col, bar_col) in zip(foo2.columns, bar.columns):
    foo2.loc[bar.index, foo_col] = bar[bar_col]

print(foo2)
```

Produces:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  2
2  0  0
3  3  4
4  0  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `update`

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,2), dtype=int), columns=['a','b'])
bar = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], index=[1,3], columns=['c','d'])

foo.update(bar.rename(columns=dict(zip(bar.columns,foo.columns))))
foo
Out[51]: 
     a    b
0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  2.0
2  0.0  0.0
3  3.0  4.0
4  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Does it have to change the columns' data types? Also, it's still rather clunky, though better than looping through the columns.

Comment: @bongbang not sure what you need then